# Existence of a function given its Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

Suppose we have a sequence $\{a_k\}_k$ of complex numbers, where the index $k$ belongs to $\mathbb Z$.

Is there any general criterion to establish if there exists an $L^1[-\pi,\pi]$  function $f$ such that $a_k$ is the $k$-th complex Fourier coefficient of $f$ for every $k$?

Notice that here I don't care about the convergence of the Fourier series to  $f$, but only about its existence. In fact, I know the bounds on $a_k$ to obtain a $C^k$ function $f$. I know also that $L^2$ functions are identified with $\ell^2$ sequences of coefficients, but I need something more general.

---

In case it is too difficult to answer the above question, I'll write also the problem I am interested in particular.

> Given $\{a_k\}_k$ the Fourier coefficients of the  $L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ function $f$, let $b_k$ be complex numbers that are either equal to $a_k$ or zero. Is it true that there exists an $L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ function $g$ whose Fourier coefficients are $b_k$ for every $k$?

Comment: I think the idea is to look at $k_r(x)=Im(\frac{1}{1-r e^{2i \pi x}}) =\frac12 \sum_{n\ne 0} r^{|n|} sign(n) e^{2i \pi nx}$ then $\lim_{r \to 1^-}\|k_r\|_{L^1} = \infty$ implies $f \mapsto \frac12\sum_{n\ne 0} r^{|n|}sign(n)  c_n(f) e^{2i \pi nx}= f \ast k_r$ isn't continuous $L^1[-1/2,1/2]\to L^1[-1/2,1/2]$. As $r \to 1^-, k_r \to pv( Im(\frac{1}{1- e^{2i \pi x}})) \approx pv(\frac{1_{|x| < 1/2}}{-2 \pi x})$. In contrary for $\Re(\frac{1}{1-r e^{2i \pi x}})$ everything works well as for the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there  is no simple necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence to be the Fourier coefficients of an $L^1$ function.

The answer to the specific  question at the end is also no, even in the apparently simple case $$b_k=\begin{cases}a_k,&(k\ge0),
\\0,&(k<0).\end{cases}$$

**Edit:** Of course I knew the OP would ask for an example. I don't know that the following quite counts as an "explicit" example,  but it's a simple proof that an example exists (simpler than what I might have said yesterday.)

The one-line proof, in terms of things "everybody knows", is just this: *The Hilbert transform is not bounded on $L^1$.*

A several-line proof, assuming no background: Define the operator $T_N$ in terms of formal trig series: $$T_N\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_ke^{ikt}=\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_ke^{ikt}.$$I'm asserting that there exists $f\in L^1$ with $T_0f\notin L^1$. Assume the contrary.

The Closed Graph Theorem shows that $T_0:L^1\to L^1$ is bounded. Now $$(T_Nf)(t)=e^{iNt}T_0(e^{-iNt}f(t)),$$ so every $T_N$ is bounded on $L^1$, with $||T_N||=||T_0||$.

Hence if $s_Nf$ is the $N$-th partial sum then $$||s_Nf||_1\le 2||T_0||\,||f||_1.$$It's easy to give an explicit counterexample to that: Let $K_N$ be the Fejer kernel and let $$f_N=2K_{2N}-K_N.$$Then $||f_N||_1\le3$ but $s_Nf_N=D_N$, the Dirichlet kernel, so $||s_Nf_N|||_1\to\infty$.

**Details:** Recall that $$K_N=\frac1N(D_1+\dots+D_N);$$hence $$f_N=\frac1N(D_{N+1}+\dots+D_{2N}).$$And of course $s_nD_k=D_n$ for $k\ge n$.

Comment: could you provide an explicit counterexample for your last statement?

Comment: @Exodd I can prove it's true...

Comment: I spent half an hour and computed $f_N$ and it seems to be equal to $e^{iNt}K_N$ so you even have $\|f_N\|_1=1$

Comment: @Exodd No, you got $f_N$ wrong. Draw  a picture of the coefficients of $K_N$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you please provide a reference for the claim that unboundedness of Hilbert transform imply non-existence of simple necessary or sufficient conditions on the Fourier coefficients?